# My custom object (detail end of a master detail relationship) is not showing up in the object field of the create record element of a flow

Tags: salesforce

I have created a custom object called Onboarding and created a master detail relationship between it (detail) and the Account (master) object.  It shows up fine in report builder and I have added it to the account page layout as a related list no problem.

I want to have a flow create records in the Onboarding object (related to an account), however, in the Create Record element, the Onboarding object is not available for selection in the 'Create a Record of this Object' field. I start with a 'Get Record' to get the account I want to use as Master, execute a screen element to gather some information, then want to do the create.  What am I missing?

Answer (score -2):

you can use the assignment operator to map the ids.